# cassandra dynamic columns with collection type values

Tags: collections, cassandra, dynamic-columns

I want to create a search index in Cassandra. The user_id is the primary key, 
next the keyword column(compound) comes, then dynamic columns should follow where the column name is some double value(score, similarity) and the value of the column is the list of file identifiers which contain the keyword and corresponds to the similarity value. I have no cassandra experience and want to know if this functionality is possible to do in Cassandra. If yes then how ????(table description??)